# Why does the compiler stop complaining about `type unit` in this case?

Tags: ocaml

If I do `let f1 x = x; x+1`, compiler will complain: `Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.`

If I do `let f2 f = f(); 5`, compiler will give `val f2 : (unit -> 'a) -> int = <fun>`.

**Questions**

1. The type system infers that `f` is a function which take `unit` as parameter and returns `'a`. But if it returns `'a`, why the compiler does not give `Warning 10`?
2. If compiler does not give `Warning 10`, it means it thinks `f()` returns `unit`, doesn't it? Then why it give `'a` as the return type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If compiler does not give Warning 10, it means it thinks f() returns unit, doesn't it?

Obviously, if the compiler gives `f2` the type `(unit -> 'a) -> int`, that means it thinks `f` returns `'a`.

What would **you** do in the compiler's place?

- Would you warn that `f2` may be applied to some functions that return non-unit results, although it may never actually be applied thus?
- Would you give `f2` the type `(unit -> unit) -> int` and make it less useful, forcing it to be used only with functions that return `()`?
- Would you invent a complicated system of postponed warnings where `f2` has type `(unit -> 'a) -> int` but produces an additional warning at compile-time if it is applied to a function that does not return `()`? Would you make this system work across modules (the postponed warnings of a function would have to be part of the module signatures)?

Warnings are only helpful hints, not guarantees. When in doubt, not emitting the warning is the usual solution (and nearly all compilers adopt this solution, not just the OCaml compilers).

Comment: `if the compiler gives f2 the type (unit -> 'a) -> int, that means it thinks f2 returns 'a` why? `f2` surely is considered to return `int`, isn't it?

Comment: @JacksonTale That was a typo, I meant “… that `f` return `'a`”

Comment: ahh, ok, that can explain

Answer (score 6):

I think this is legacy behaviour from the compiler. Use `-strict-sequence` to fix it:

```
$ ocaml
# let f2 f = f(); 5;;
val f2 : (unit -> 'a) -> int = <fun>
```

But:

```
$ ocaml -strict-sequence
# let f2 f = f(); 5;;
val f2 : (unit -> unit) -> int = <fun>
```

If you use `ocamlbuild`, you should put this in your `_tags` file:

```
true: strict_sequence
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me add a bit to Pascal's answer.

Try

```
let f1'  (y : 'a)      x = y; x+1
let f1'' (y : 'a list) x = y; x+1

let f2'  (f : unit -> 'a)      = f(); 5
let f2'' (f : unit -> 'a list) = f(); 5
```

`f1'` and `f2'` give you no warning but `f1''` and `f2''` do.

Why only for `f1''` and `f2''`? Since OCaml type checker surely knows that the types of `e1` in `e1 ; e2` are not `unit` (they are `'a list`).

For `f1'` and `f2'`, the type of `e1` is a type variable `'a`. They may be instantiated to `unit` depending on how `f1'` and `f2'` are used, so there is a chance that they can be used "properly". Thinking of this possibility, the compiler does not warn them.

I personally prefer to simply force the type of `e1`'s type in `e1 ; e2` be `unit`. But OCaml is more relaxed here.

Comment: @JacksonTale Yes, `'a` can be instantiated into any type including `unit`, otherwise it would be impossible to apply the identity (of type `'a -> 'a` to `()`. But this is very useful (and thus possible): `let id x = x in id ()`

Comment: @PascalCuoq ah, ok, I thought `unit` type is special and complement `'a` type